# How to write a dictionary comprehension and deriving a new dictionary with some changes

Tags: python

This is the code that is given:

`
}

```
and I want to write a dictionary comprehension to derive a new dict object, called brazilian_players2, that maps a Brazilian player's name to his position!

I came up with:
```

brazilian_players2 = { 'Brazil' : players['Brazil'] for x in players['Brazil'] }

```
but this only gives me the complete team.
I would like to have this outcome:
```

{'Júlio César', 'Goalkeeper'}
...
}

````
or like 
```{"player_name", "player_position"}```
````

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "every Brazilian player one with his name and position." It would be helpful if you provide the expected output. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Comment: Do you mean to create a dictionary of the form `{"player_name": "player_position"}`? Can you clarify and post the expected output?

Comment: Yes almost. ```{"Name": "player_name", "Position":  "player_position"}```

Comment: It's still not clear what is your expected output. Is it a list of dicts?

Comment: This won't be possible for all the players, as "Name" and "Position" would become key and hence, key can't be duplicate. You may have one suggested like @Tomeriko or you may have a dictionary of "Name" list and "Position" list.

Comment: It's a new dict from the given dict, but only with the key "Brazil" and de values Name and Position I suppose

Comment: But dictionaries can only have unique keys... It can either be: `{name: position}` or `[{"name": name, "position": position}]`

Comment: Thanks, got your point. Then ```{name: position}```would be the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each player is a tuple of the form - `(number, name, position, [])`. So you need to grab that information accordingly:

#### list of dicts

```py
brazil = []
for _, name, position, _ in players["Brazil"]:
    brazil.append({"name": name, "position": position})
```

Or as a list-comprehension:

```
brazil = [{"name": name, "position": position} for _, name, position, _ in players["Brazil"]]
```

#### single dict

```py
brazil = {}
for _, name, position, _ in players["Brazil"]:
    brazil[name] = position
```

Or as a dict-comprehension:

```
brazil = {name: position for _, name, position, _ in players["Brazil"]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested dictionary, so players['Brazil'] just dumps everything in the array that you have nested there.  You need to access the nested information with some sort of loop.  Might be a cleaner way to do this, but here's mine:

```
for x in players['Brazil']:
   playerName = x[1]
   playerPos = x[2]
   print("%s, %s" % (playerName, playerPos))
```

You can dump those variables into your format (dict or tuple) from there.